# Кавычки в диалоге при переспрашивании

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Не уверен, что правильно сформулировал тему. Нужно ли ставить кавычки в вопросительных предложениях такого типа:

1. – Они всегда так? – спросил Дима.

   – Как так? – огрызнулся он.

   ---
2. – А разве... – начала Маша.

   – Что разве? – перебил он.

Answer (score 2):

Я исправила Ваш вопрос (надеюсь, не поставила его с ног на голову). Заменила "запятые" на "кавычки", потому что только в них пунктограмма (может быть заключена). И союзные слова нам не мешают.

---

Да, приведённые Вами примеры жаждут кавычек (это же мини-цитаты):

*– Они всегда так? – спросил Дима.*

*– Как "так"? – огрызнулся он.*

---

*– А разве... – начала Маша.*

*– Что "разве"? – перебил он.*

Comment: Но всегда ли должны ставиться в таких случаях кавычки, или вполне допустимо написание без них?