# Как писать двойное произношение слова при ответе на вопрос?

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

Первый вариант:

> — Ты как в Москву приехал?
>
> — Как-как, значит? Да вот так! На поезде!

Второй вариант:

> — Ты как в Москву приехал?
>
> — Как, как, значит? Да вот так! На поезде!

Третий вариант:

> — Ты как в Москву приехал?
>
> — Как «как», значит? Да вот так! На поезде!

Comment: Примеры крайне неудачные, так что я вообще не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос. Если он про то, как пишется "как-как", то через дефис: https://i.imgur.com/Hp7Xj6R.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Возможные варианты оформления:**

— Ты как в Москву приехал?
— Что значит "как"? Да вот так. На поезде!

— Ты как в Москву приехал?
— Как, как! Да вот так. На поезде!

**Примеры оформления из Нацкорпуса:**

― Что ты заладил "как, как"! ― рассердился Двинятин. [Запись LiveJournal (2004)]

― Эй, сестрички, как ваши дела? ― Как, как? ― огрызнулась Зина. ― Никак, вот как. [Виктор Кологрив. Медовый луг // «Мурзилка», 2002]

**Примечание**

Словарный вариант ― это "***как-как***", Но в Нацкорпусе есть варианты только через запятую.

Две записи **различаются на слух**: при дефисе слитное произношение, а в случае постановки запятой перечислительная интонация.

Comment: Первый пример очевидным образом ошибочен, потому что в кавычки берётся подлинная цитата, а не удвоенная. К тому же имеется глагол говорения поэтому необходимо двоеточие. Верное оформление: *Что ты заладил: "как", "как"! ― рассердился Двинятин.*

Comment: Не согласна с вашим вариантом. Это не прямая речь, а обозначение словосочетания "как, как" в виде цельного выражения. У автора ― лучше!  Зачем нам лишние знаки?  И запись там по правилам.

Comment: К тому ж в Нацкорпусе аж 107 вхождений с "как-как". Надо хитрее пользоваться встроенным туда поиском, хе-хе) https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=bdash&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&morph1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=semx&morph2=

Comment: Ладно,  учту. Только такое умение на гарантирует правильный выбор, если пользователи не видят для  двух этих форм  разницы ни в содержании, ни в произношении, ни в соответствии конкретной ситуации, ага?

Comment: Разница у Розенталя прослеживается, если прочитать параграфы 16 и 17 в главе "Пунктуация". В частности: "5) [через дефис пишутся] наречия с подчеркнутым выражением присущего им значения: едва-едва, еле-еле, чуть-чуть и т. п.".

Comment: А что мне делать с этим "подчеркнутым значением", для чего оно подчеркнуто? Вот в наречии "еле-еле" повтор усиливает смысл (очень медленно).  А вы что подчеркивает в "как-как", дополнительную коннотацию? А что она выражает? Мне кажется, что нетерпение и раздражение, а в нашем случае этого нет. Люди спокойно разговаривают, вполне себе "добросердечно".

Comment: Напомню ваш вариант: *— Как, как! Да вот так! На поезде!* Прям сплошное спокойствие. С тремя восклицательными знаками и рубленым набором предложений.

Comment: Это дружеская ирония, не более того.  Язык надо чувствовать. :))   Наша уникальная система письма позволяет выразить самые тонкие оттенки речи,  разве нет?  Если, конечно, знать ее интонационный смысл.  А восклицательные знаки я сейчас уберу, я вроде бы не все их не ставила...

Comment: Главное — выражая тонкие оттенки, не свалиться в грубые ошибки.

Comment: А вы будьте внимательны, тогда не свалитесь. Кстати, восклицание может быть радостным.

Comment: Особенно часто люди выражают радость словосочетанием "да вот так!"

Comment: Здесь я с вами согласна. Но это сочетание может иметь разную эмоциональную окраску, так что учитывайте это.

Answer (score 1):

Тема уже поднималась на форуме. При переспрашивании цитируемое слово заключается в кавычки. [Кавычки в диалоге при переспрашивании](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448745/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8) В ваших примерах тот же механизм.

Comment: Это совсем другая тема, речь идет не о кавычках, а о форме письма (дефис, запятые).

Comment: @Sharon  Речь и о кавычках тоже (третий вариант в вопросе).

Comment: Ситуации совершенно разные, это надо учитывать.  Вот что я имела в виду. Поэтому одно оформление не образец для другого.